# split rows in a column and find the number of each word occurs, finding which one has the highest count using bar chart

Tags: python, pandas

- i have a dataframe
- i would like to split the string in each row,
- and find the number of each word appears, count all the words
- and make the bar chart for visualizing the highest one.

The only thing i've done is to split the string from "[x|x|x]" into "[x,x,x]", but the way to count each word is confused.

```py
df_genres = df.copy()
df_genres.genres.head()

    0    Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
    1    Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
    2           Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller
    3     Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy
    4                        Action|Crime|Thriller
    Name: genres, dtype: object
-----------------------------------------------------------------
s = df_genres['genres'].str.split('|')
s.head()

    0    [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
    1    [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
    2            [Adventure, Science Fiction, Thriller]
    3     [Action, Adventure, Science Fiction, Fantasy]
    4                         [Action, Crime, Thriller]
    Name: genres, dtype: object

- count each word like"Action, Adventure, Fiction, etc",
- make the bar chart and see which word has the highest bar.
```

Comment: What exactly is your question? Counting can be done using [collections.Counter](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.Counter). Creating a bar chart could be done in many ways, depending on how you want it too look. For example, see [matplotlib](https://matplotlib.org/3.1.0/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.bar.html).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not very elegant but this should do the work.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

df_genres = pd.DataFrame({'genres': ["Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller", "Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller", "Adventure|Science Fiction|Thriller", "Action|Adventure|Science Fiction|Fantasy", "Action|Crime|Thriller" ] })

genres_count = {j : ''.join(df_genres.genres.tolist()).count(j) for i in df_genres.genres.str.split('|').tolist() for j in i}

pd.DataFrame({'genres': list(genres_count.keys()), 'count': list(genres_count.values())}).plot.bar(x='genres', y='count')

plt.show()
```